# What is the Lebesgue measure of ball in the Euclidean space?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I know that Lebesgue measure of the  integral  $[-R, R]\subset \mathbb R$ is  its length  that is $2R.$

Let $d\geq 2$ and consider $B_{R}=\{ x\in \mathbb R^d: |x|\leq R \}$ for some $R>0$.

> What is the  Lebesgue measure of $B_{R}$ in $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Comment: Lebesgue measure can be seen as an extension of the intuitive definition of what you would use to quantify length, aera or volume for the first three dimensions. In other words, the Lebesgue measure coincides with those quantities for "simple" (in some sense) geometric objects.